# python when loading shp with cartopy function

Tags: python, cartopy

Im getting an error:

```
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000000
```

While trying to load an shp with sr.Reader() function.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as cor
import numpy as np
import cartopy.io.shapereader as sr
crs = ccrs.PlateCarree()
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10), dpi = 600)
ax1 = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection = crs)
geom = sr.Reader(r"D:\CS\Krigin\shp\jiangsu.shp").geometries()
ax1.add_geometries(geom, crs)
```

then I get an error:

```
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000000
```

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: This looks like an installation/package version error. How did you install your environment?

Comment: install the function by anaconda in the base env. conda install cartopy

Comment: have you installed other packages with `conda-forge`, e.g. `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas` etc? package conflicts between the anaconda `defaults` channel and `conda-forge` can cause low-level errors like this. I'd try uninstalling anaconda and installing [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html), then installing all the packages you need into a fresh environment with `conda create -n myenv -c conda-forge [packages]`.

Comment: yes, I installed other packages with conda-forge. Thanks for your help, I will have a try.